# Some apps don't open even if deleted and reinstalled!

Tags: ios, applications, jailbreak, crash

I have a problem here. Some apps I have installed don't even open and have this icon on my Springboard.

[image]

My iOS version is 7.0.1. Jailbroken.

Two of my Applications have ended like this. I tried reinstalling the Apps, but nothing.

I haven't installed any tweaks recently and it just happened.
I also disabled some tweaks that could be suspicious and I reinstalled the App, but after 2 days, the app did the same thing.

**I can confirm that 8/10 of my last automatically Updated Apps crash on launch** and some icons don't show (as in the Screenshot).

**Any tips?**

Answer (score 1):

Install a tweak called iWipe cache, it will respring your Spring board and will do the deal.